# Output text to a file with a class method java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a `valet` class method that should write an hourly wage to a file:

```
public void hourlyOverall() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("wage info");
    new FileOutputStream("wage info", true);
    hourlyOverall = tips / hours + hourlyWage;
    out.println(hourlyOverall);
}
```

However, when I run `valet.hourlyOverall()` in my `main` method, the file "wage info" is created but nothing is written to it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Close the `OutputStream`

Answer (score 1):

First of all use `try-catch` for `Exception` handling and then in the `finally` block close the `OutputStream`

`out.flush();`

Somthing like this

```
try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("wage info");
        hourlyOverall=tips/hours+hourlyWage;
        out.println(hourlyOverall);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        out.flush();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is another way to solve your problem, but using another classes

```
public class valet {
    public static void main(String []args)throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            hourlyOverall()
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex+"\n");
        }
    }

    public void hourlyOverall() throws IOException
    {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("wage info");
        hourlyOverall=tips/hours+hourlyWage;
        out.write(hourlyOverall+"\r\n");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't declare an anonymous `FileOutputStream` and you should probably close your `PrintWriter`,

```
PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter("wage info");
// new FileOutputStream("wage info",true);
hourlyOverall=tips/hours+hourlyWage;
out.println(hourlyOverall);
out.close();                             // <-- like that
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this (if java7 or above) :

```
 public void hourlyOverall()
    {
        try (PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter("wage info")){
           //new FileOutputStream("wage info",true);
           hourlyOverall=tips/hours+hourlyWage;
           out.println(hourlyOverall);
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html